# I am trying to use the Node command: 'node js-code.js' I am getting a 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error code

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use  'node js-code.js' to run javaScript in my command line. I get this error:

```
'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' along with 'requireStack: []'
```

I tried 'n latest' and received this error:

```
n latest
  installing : node-v20.4.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/20.4.0
mkdir: /usr/local/n: Permission denied

Error: sudo required (or change ownership, or define N_PREFIX)
```

I tried 'npm i -g n' and was able to install the latest Node with the additional code:

```
N_PREFIX=$HOME/.local n stable
```

Although after Node.js version  v19.6.0. was installed, 'node js-code.js' still rendered this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tyleradams/Desktop/nodeTest/js-code.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1060:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:905:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: []
    }
```

Has anyone run in to this problem?
Thank you

Comment: You posted a lot of code, that is ok! However, the js_code.js might be the source of your problem and we have no idea what is inside it. Maybe if you share a simple snippet of it people can help you quicker.